# resize all images in gridview to fit the 3x5

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-gridview

I have a GridView with 3 columns and 5 rows of images.

currently configureg like...

```
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/faces_gridview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:numColumns="3" >
</GridView>
```

I want the images inside to resize themselves to fit 3x5 grid which is different in each phone. how can I tell the GridView to resize the images based on the grid size that I want ?

numColumns sets the columns but it does not reassure me that there will be 5 rows visible in the screen. I don't want to use a scroller.

Comment: for image view android:scaleType="fitXY".

Answer (score 1):

as per [GridView auto fit images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5872530/gridview-auto-fit-images) & [GridView not stretching to all screens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7053016/gridview-not-stretching-to-all-screens)

try

```
android:scaleType="fitXY" in image view 

and

 android:stretchMode="columnWidth" in grid view
```

Comment: the pictures are scaled and not cropped which is good but only 3 rows are visible instead of the all 5. I will try to fetch the screen height and try to max it with this data.

Comment: yup even not sure about weight in grid view

Comment: can't i set max height of gridview somehow ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8697681/android-gridview-adjusting-to-screen-size

Comment: but as per this https://groups.google.com/group/android-beginners/browse_thread/thread/1ee2ddccd645bb71 weight can work for us

Comment: or make your own custom one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7545915/gridview-rows-overlapping-how-to-make-row-height-fit-the-tallest-item

Comment: Why is fitXY better than centerCrop here?